# Can i store shiro configuration in another datastore?

Tags: apache, configuration, shiro

Is it possible to store shiro configuration in some data store like ldap or oracle database?

Or only **shiro.ini** file is the way to load and store configuration?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Shiro configuration in another location.  However, it will require programatically configuring Shiro by instantiating a SecurityManager and then binding the various configuration components (realms, urls, caching) to the newly instantiated SecurityManager.

http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html

This link while specific to Shiro + Guice also covers some of the manual configuration steps you can take with Shiro.

http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html